# MX Notify Control unsubscribe link

Tags: notification, mailing, mailinglist

Anyone out there use MX Notify Control?  I am using the extension to send an email to a mailing list for a new channel entry.

It uses a standard template as the email, problem is I need to include an unsubscribe link in the template.  Since it is not using a mailing list template I have no way to include a mailing list unsubscribe link.

Anyone know how you can create an unsubscribe link OUTSIDE of a mailing list template?

Comment: someone mentioned this but I can't seem to get it to work

{exp:query sql="SELECT authcode FROM exp_mailing_list WHERE email = '{email}'"}
http://www.DOMAIN.com/index.php?ACT=5&id;={authcode}
{/exp:query}

Answer (score 1):

There is no tag for {unsubscribe_url} or {unsubscribe_link}.

As you are using the MX Notify Control extension and creating your own email notify template.

Within this template, you can try following SQL with query module to create unsubscribe link for an email:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT exp_actions.action_id, exp_mailing_list.authcode FROM exp_mailing_list, exp_actions WHERE email='{mbr_email}' AND class='Mailinglist' AND method='unsubscribe'"}
<a href="{site_url}index.php?ACT={action_id}&id={authcode}">Unsubscribe</a>
{/exp:query}
```

You might need to update the {email_address} in WHERE condition.

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: You are correct I am using using the MX Notify Control extension and creating my own email notify template.

I tried your code and nothing appears in the email I am receiving. I tried {email_address} and {email} both did nothing.  

Any suggestions?

Comment: {email_address} isn't any tag. I just put for example. Could you please try with {mbr_email}. I updated the query in my answer for the same.

Comment: hmm still noting being sent in the email from the template.  looking on phpmyadmin it looks like it should be 'email'

I would attach a screenshot but not sure how to do it on here

Comment: The template will be parsed for each email of mailing list to fetched the parsed template content into email message area and {mbr_email} should be replaced with that email. The query seems something fine to me. Let me check more so that we can find any prominent way. Also, could you confirm if you are using "Mailing List" module or MX Notify Control's plugin tag to save emails.

Comment: MX Notify has the ability to send to a mailing list that is created in the EE Mailing List module.  So all emails are being entered through the EE Mailing List module.